# Redprob.ado file installation

Tags: panel, stata

I’m trying to use the dynamic RE panel logit model.

I downloaded the `redprob.ado`, `redprob.hlp`, `redpmod_ll.ado` files from Prof. Mark Stewart's website and installed as follows.

- Create `ado` and `personal` folder in my C: drive.
- Save those 3 files in `personal` folder.
- Typed `net set ado c:\ado\personal`
- Typed `adopath + "c:\ado\personal”`
- Type `ssc install redprob`

But the following message came out.

```
ssc install: "redprob" not found at SSC, type -findit redprob-
(To find all packages at SSC that start with r, type -ssc describe r-)”
```

What is the way to install and use `redprob`?

Answer (score 0):

As you noted these files should be downloaded from Mark Stewart's site, namely http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/soc/economics/staff/academic/stewart/stata

The third file is called `redpmod_ll.ado`, and not as you originally typed.

They are not on SSC, so the `ssc` command is completely irrelevant. What you did is like saying "fetch me this program from Warwick" and then "and now fetch me this program from Connecticut" when it is only at Warwick.

The StataCorp recommendation is to use `c:\ado\plus`, but what you did should have worked.

Try it with

```
which redprob
```

and Stata should be able to find the program and tell you where it is.

Answer (score 0):

If you have manually downloaded the files, simply pasting them into `c:\ado\personal` should do the work. Stata will automatically load commands from this folder when it starts. Create the folder if it doesn't exist.